# Android Studio: changing package name broke tests

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit

I have an unexpected problem. I changed package name of my app (using Refactor, ofc) and I have fixed gradle.build to make sure new package name is registered there. Cleaned and rebuilt my project but still, when I try to run the tests I get:

"Test events were not received" message with this output:

```
....
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.example.testApp2.MyTest](--tests filter)
```

What else remains to be changed for this to work? I'm kind of new to Gradle and expected it to be more resilient to simple changes like package name changes :D

P.S. Test package name is the same as src package name, I checked

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT! The problem was that tests in my class were annotated with @Test from Junit5 instead of JUnit4. As soon as I used @Test from org.junit it was all ok!

Why is that, anyone?